# Whats the Problem with the socket in my server?

Tags: python, sockets, server

Thats my code

```
import sqlite3
import socket
import re
import face_recognition
import os, sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from recognition import FaceRecognizer
from SalaryDemo import Salary
from Camera import SignUpCamera


def main():
    # Connect to the SQLite database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info('users')")
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    if not result:
        # If the 'users' table does not exist, create it
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                              username TEXT,
                                              password TEXT)''')
        cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN user_data TEXT")


    
    # Set up the server
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(('localhost', 8080))
    server.listen()
    open = True
    # Wait for incoming connections
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print(f'Connected by {addr}')
    while True:
    
        # Receive login/sign-up data from the client
        data = client.recv(1024)
        action, username, password = data.decode().split(':')
    
        if action == 'login':
            recognizer = FaceRecognizer()
            recognizer.load_faces("faces")
            if recognizer.recognize_face(username):
                cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', (username, password))
                result = cursor.fetchone()
            else:
                print(f"{username} not matched!")
                result = None
            
            if result:
                # If the login is successful, send the user's data back to the client
                user_data = f'{result[0]}:{result[1]}:{result[2]}'
                msg_to_client = "welcome " + username
                client.send(msg_to_client.encode())
                sl = Salary()
                sl.getSallary(username)                
            else:
                # If the login is unsuccessful, send an error message back to the client
                client.send('Invalid login'.encode())
    
        elif action == 'signup':
            cm = SignUpCamera()
            # Check if the password is strong enough
            if not re.search(r'[A-Z]', password) or not re.search(r'[a-z]', password) or not re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
                client.send('Password is not strong enough'.encode())
            else:
                # Check if the username is already in use
                cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', (username,))
                result = cursor.fetchone()

                if result:
                    # If the username is already in use, send an error message back to the client
                    client.send('Username already in use'.encode())
                else:
                    # If the username is available, insert a new row into the 'users' table
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password, user_data) VALUES (?, ?, ? || '.jpg')", (username, password, username.lower()))
                    conn.commit()
                    cm.main(username)
                    client.send('Sign-up successful'.encode())
    
        client.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

it works but everytime i run it after it finished doing its thing i get this error

```
  Message=[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
  Source=C:\Users\Bar12\source\repos\final-project-afek-and-liam-authentication_client_server\ServerSideProject\ServerSideProject\ServerSideProject.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\Bar12\source\repos\final-project-afek-and-liam-authentication_client_server\ServerSideProject\ServerSideProject\ServerSideProject.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
```

Please help i am kinda new to this

the code should just wait for a new user to try to login but insted i get this error after a user joins

Answer (score 1):

The problematic part of your code boils down to this:

```
while True:
    
    # Receive login/sign-up data from the client
    data = client.recv(1024)
    ... 
    client.close()
```

You read from the socket, (later write to the socket) and then close the socket. Then you try to read from the **already closed** socket again - resulting in this error.

It is not clear what the actual purpose of the `client.close()` should have been at this part of the code, but it clearly causes the problem you see.